# Save data between activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a login activity in my application which has a method that adds a fragment on top of it using fragment manager. I have two EditText fields in the fragment (name and password).

However when I change the orientation on my device, the text that is written in the EditText fields is deleted. The two EditText fields have been given two unique ID's in the XML-file (which normally helps to save the information within them when the orientation is changed) but the value inside them isn't preserved when orientation changes. How do I preserve the values inside of the EditText fields in this case?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: remove your android:configChanges in AndroidManifest if you have set it

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of links about same question on Stackoverflow, check it.

But your response:

Inside Fragment class you have the onSaveInstanceState method, override it in your fragment and put (putString) in the bundle (from method params) the variables you want to save, in this case your texts written in your edittexts.

Later in onActivityCreated get the values and set them in your EditTexts.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("name", etName.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String name = savedInstanceState.getString("name", "");
        String pass = savedInstanceState.getString("password", "");
        etName.setText(name);
        etPassword.setText(pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I've tried out so many different things but I cant understand why it won't save the EditText input when orientation changes...